# Fill PDF Input fields with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, input, field

How is it possible to fill PDF input fields with javascript ( if it is even possible ). In my case I want to create a javascript in which I can fill a HTML form, the data which the user put in the HTML form should be saved into the PDF Input Field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking on how to populate existing fields in a PDF with Node and after a while I found [pdf-fill-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-fill-form) as a great option to do so.

And you can use it really easy

```
  // First get the Id of the value you need to populate in the pdf

  const pdfFillForm = require('pdf-fill-form');
  const fs = require('fs');
  let pdfFields = pdfFillForm.readSync('test/files/axapdf.pdf');
  console.log(pdfFields);

  var pdf = pdfFillForm.writeSync('pdf_to_fill.pdf',

    {'65536':'Set the value here'}, { "save": 'pdf' });


  fs.writeFileSync('filled_test_sync1.pdf', pdf);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`jpdf`](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/) for the same, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o24eaaz0/) demonstrating the same.

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297,210]);//page size
 var options = {
     pagesplit: true
    };
 pdf.addHTML($('#text_land')[0],options, function () {//data to print
 pdf.save('Test.pdf');
 });
```

study the fiddle, you must find what you are seeking for.

Comment: I believe the question is asking how to populate an input field in an existing PDF, rather than just draw the input into a PDF.