# Fill a PDF form with input tables

Tags: javascript, python, r, pdf

I have a PDF file with two kinds of fields: simple text box and drop-down menus with a list of choices. I also have separate plain text tables with information to fill those fields. Ideally, I would like to take this PDF with the fields empty and fill it according to the information I have in the tables.

Therefore, I was wondering if someone can help me to try to solve this problem or at least point me in the right direction. The closest thing that I have found as a solution is to write a javascript that fills the PDF. However, I am afraid that I am not familiar with modifying PDFs nor javascript, and without a clear example it would be difficult for me to understand what is going on. I am familiar with python and R so if anyone knows a solution using those that would be great (I am okay learning new stuff too!).

One last note, the PDF does not come from me, I am trying to avoid copy-pasting work for my colleagues. The tables do come from me so I can modify them as I please.

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide the code.

Comment: Apologies if I have not been clearer, I don't have any code. I am asking for advice because I do not know how to start. The little that I found is not exactly what I want , for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876459/fill-pdf-input-fields-with-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322137/fill-data-in-existing-pdf-form-using-nodejs). In the first link, someone posted a bit of code but I am not sure if I can use it for what I want, I am not familiar with javascript as I mention in my post so I might have overlooked something.